# IDE for context free grammars for natural languages?

Tags: computational-linguistics, software, chomsky-hierarchy

Is there any such thing as a Integrated Development Environment for context free grammars (or any variant on a formal, machine parsable grammar) that target natural languages?  The ones for BNF grammars seem to be overwhelmingly aimed at turning language into machine executable code. I would imagine that a similar tool for natural language would let the user write a grammar, evaluate it for mistakes and parse example sentence to trees or generate sample sentences given a dictionary of lexemes/tokens.

Answer (score 4):

[ANTLRWorks](http://www.antlr.org/works/index.html) is an editor for [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) grammars.

ANTLR allows you to write BNF context free grammars (which also produces code).

ANTLRWorks allows you to try examples strings on the grammar and displays the parsing.

As to natural language, if you have a BNF grammar for one (I think there is a non-trivial but still non-inclusive grammar for English in the javacc parser code), then you can use it with some changes with ANTLR.

Comment: How does ANTLR handle syntactic ambiguity? AFAIK, and according to
Wikipedia, ANTLER is an LL(*) parser. This is hardly the ideal tool
for developing perspicuous natural language grammar. The role of an
IDE is to make the creative work easier. Imposing unneeded constraints
to begin with is hardly the way to do it.

Comment: @babou: I didn't go in to how CFG is particularly good (or natural) at natural language. All I'm saying is that ANTLRWorks is a good IDE for BNF (for ANTLR). You're going to have difficulties ('unneeded constraints') already if you're starting with CFG. Do you know of any looser formalisms (link grammars?)? And do they have IDEs?

Comment: My point is not that CFG are not adequate for NL parsing. Many people
are quite happy with it, and that is all the OP is asking for anyway.
The point is that ANTLRWorks is intended to help developing grammars
for ANTLER, which uses only a very restricted subclass of CF grammars, not
even all the deterministic ones. So full CFG is already a much looser
formalism. I am not questionning the quality of ANTLRWorks, but an IDE
for Java is of no use to a Python programmer, even if no IDE is available
for Python. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @babou Yes, you've misunderstood; you've confused the problems of an IDE with that of the grammar. ANTLRWorks is an IDE for ANTLR, whatever it does. Your comment sounds like a complaint about ANTLR, but the OP is asking about IDEs. In your analogy, Java and Python can both compute all functions, and maybe you don't like Java, but the IDE is the one that exists, and not for Python. So you can't do LALR grammars in ANTLR; well, if you want to use LALR, then don't use ANTLRWorks.

Comment: You then agree that ANTLRWorks will do only LL grammars. I am
saying this class is too restricted for NL use, while you are saying
it is good enough with the advantage of an IDE. Other users may agree
with either one of us.  What matters is for them to be aware that this
is an issue they have to consider. I fear that the IDE main use is
to compensate for the difficulty of putting grammars in LL form, and
understanding how it works.

Comment: @babou - I can't remember which grammars ANTLR deals so I trust you when you say that LL is all it does. - I would expect that any IDE is geared towards a well-defined formalism like BNF. - The other answer, LingBench, seems to contradict that (but I can't speak to how easy or difficult it is or what its grammar restrictions are).

Comment: Again I am not disparaging ANTLR or ANTLRWorks. They are considered
very good for what they were intended for. But they are no
swiss-knife. The limitation to LL is stated on wikipedia, and given
the number of happy followers of ANTLR, I am pretty sure it is
accurate. It means that ANTLR will not take all of BNF (i.e. context-free) but only a subclass. - - - - -  It is not actually
true that all IDE are geared towards a single language or
formalism. There is also what is called IDE generators. But it is true
that some IDE tools may be formalism dependent, though much less than
you would think.

Answer (score 4):

You may find this interesting: [LingBench IDE](http://www.natlantech.com/lingbench_ide.html).

From the product description:

> LingBench IDE is an Integrated Development Environment for Linguists and Computer Linguists to Model a Natural Language by describing the morphology, the syntax, the lexical and other aspects of a language in detail.

It seems to be an old and unsupported piece of software though.